# Where do my DoubleClick Adsense payments go?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-dfp

I'm looking into switching from Google Adsense to DoubleClick so that I can use custom adverts.

As well as this I would still like to use Adsense through DoubleClick.

How will payments be linked to my Adsense account? Do I need to set something up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Adsense through DFP, all Adsense revenue will be visible and paid through your Adsense account.